# Python list/dict comprehension summing a dict list key by another key in the same dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum, list-comprehension

Been thinking how to convert this to a one liner if possible:

```
activities = 
[ {'type': 'Run', 'distance': 12345, 'other_stuff': other ...},                   
  {'type': 'Ride', 'distance': 12345, 'other_stuff': other ...},  
  {'type': 'Swim', 'distance': 12345, 'other_stuff': other ...} ]
```

currently am using:

```
grouped_distance = defaultdict(int)
for activity in activities:  
    act_type = activity['type']
    grouped_distance[act_type] += activity['distance']

# {'Run': 12345, 'Ride': 12345, 'Swim': 12345}
```

Have tried
`grouped_distance = {activity['type']:[sum(activity['distance']) for activity in activities]}`
this is not working where it says activity['type'] is not defined.

**Edited**
Fix some variables typo as noticed by @Samwise

**Update:**
Did some a benchmark on  all the solution that was posted.
10 millions items, with 10 different types:

Method 1 (Counter): 7.43s
Method 2 (itertools @chepner): 8.64s
Method 3 (groups @Dmig): 19.34s
Method 4 (pandas @d.b): 32.73s
Method 5 (Dict @d.b): 10.95s

Tested on Raspberry Pi 4 to further see the differences.
Do correct me if I "name" the method wrongly.

Thank you everyone and @Dmig,  @Mark, @juanpa.arrivillaga has piqued my interest in performance. Shorter/Neater ≠ Higher Performance. Wanted to just asked if I write it in a one liner form for it to look neater, but I have learnt a lot more than that.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a particularly good candidate for a one-liner unless you want to sort and groupby.

Comment: I think you can write this as one long and hard to understand line (@Mark already gave a hint how) but this is a bad idea.

Comment: This code doesn't run at all.  Did you mix up `result` and `grouped_distance`?

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame(activities).groupby("type").sum().to_dict("index")`

Comment: Do you actually need to do sums?  Your sample data doesn't have any repeats of the same type, so you could get the desired result by just doing `{a['type']: a['distance'] for a in activities}`.

Comment: @Samwise  edited the variable. mixed it out while transferring the code over. Thank you so much!

Sample data is just a small sample, but will have hundreds of entries of different type.

Comment: @d.b oh yes, thank you so much, totally forget about pandas!

Comment: Your solution is *perfectly fine*

Comment: "Been thinking how to convert this to a one liner " Why? Why does this have to be a one-liner? You should think about making your code *readable*, *maintainable*, and avoiding unnecessarily inefficient algorithms if possible (especially if trivially possible). Your code is perfectly readable and as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is good as it is, but if you really want one-liner:

```py
act = [{'type': 'run', 'distance': 4}, {'type': 'run', 'distance': 3}, {'type': 'swim', 'distance': 5}]

groups = {
  t: sum(i['distance'] for i in act if i['type'] == t)
  for t in {i['type'] for i in act}  # set with all possible activities
}

print(groups)  # {'run': 7, 'swim': 5}
```

---

**UPD:** I've made some performance research, comparing this answer to answer which uses `group(sortedby(...))`. Turns out, on ten million entries and 10 different types, this approach loses to `group(sortedby(...))` with `18.14` seconds against `10.12`. So, while it is more readable, it is less efficient on bigger lists and especially with more distinct types in it (because it iterates initial list one time per each distinct type).

But take note, the initial straight way to do it from question would take only `5` seconds!

*This answer is only to show one-liner for educational purposes, solution from question has much better performance. You should not use this instead of one in question, unless, as I said, you really want/need one-liner.*

Comment: This answers the question, but worth noting that you traded a non-one-liner with O(n) performance for a one-liner with O(n^2) performance (although helped a bit with the set).

Comment: @Mark don't fully understand, does that mean that using group will take twice the performance? Able to share some insights on how you gauge the performance? might be useful in the next time!

Comment: @Dmig thank you so much! this works as well, it is cleaner and more readable!

Comment: @Cytan notice that the code iterates over the list `act` more than once. It does it for every type of event you have. So if you have a list of 10 items and 5 types, it needs to look at 50 items as opposed to just 10 items in your original code.

Comment: @Cytan I've updated answer to contain more information about benchmarked performance of suggested solutions

Comment: This is a bad solution, it is O(N*2) when it is trivially accomplished in O(N) using the typical grouping idiom.

Comment: @Cytan don't use this solution

Comment: Compare it to the OP's original solution. I bet it beats *both* of the answers

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well, before you've made this comment I already compared it. As Mark noticed, it does answer the question, since OP wanted one-liner. I don't say it is best solution, it just provides good readability without any dependencies.

Comment: @Mark thank you mark for explaining, now it really pique my interest about performance. Shorter Code doesn't always leads to higher performance.

Comment: @Dmig thank you so much Dmig. Was just starting out in python, got this misconception where if my code is shorter it should be "faster", and also wanted it to be neater, thus was exploring for a one liner solution. But still thank you for helping, testing and explaining. Didn't expect to learn so much for a one liner thing.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
from operator import itemgetter


by_type = itemgetter('type')
distance = itemgetter('distance')
result = {
    k: sum(map(distance, v))
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(activities, key=by_type), by_type)
    }
```

When iterating over the `groupby` instance, `k` will be one of the activity types, and `v` will be an iterable of activities having type `k`.

Comment: I'll note, the OP's solution is probably perfectly fine as it is. This solution is still technically less efficient

Comment: Depending on the use case, the declarative nature of something like this (though I really wish `groupby` supported something like `groupby(activities, by_type, autosort=True)`) may provide readability improvements that trump runtime efficiency.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree (although, I find the OP's solution perfectly readable), but I still think it should be at least noted

Comment: Yup, just providing a "defense" for why trading efficiency for readability might be worthwhile.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you’re right, have done some benchmark to see the time taken. Really amaze by how you all can just gauge the efficiency. Thought it will be the same, since it only loop one time.